# Restarting rails delayed job won't update running jobs locked_by, and they won't run again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Say I'm having some delayed job that is currently locked and running, then I decided to restart delayed jobs for some reason(may be new code). I use the following commands

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -n 10 stop;
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -n 10 start;
```

However, checking that specific job, it is still locked by the old process, and locked_at is the same old date, and it is not running, and it won't get locked by the new delayed jobs processes since it's marked as locked. So I have to manually update its lock fields to nil, so that it gets locked by new processes and run again.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the values by setting `locked_at` and `locked_by` to `null`.

Then `restart` the `delayed_job`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to to do anything manual, I just want the whole thing to be automated. Also setting them to nil before restarting will cause them immediately to be locked again before restarting, so the same problem will rise again.